# Are bounties ONLY used to get attention?

Tags: discussion

I have wondering that maybe people will make a bounty on their question to get more attention and more answers and then USE the answer that accurately answered the question but NOT give out the bounty. Have this ever happened and if so, how will this be dealt? There are lots of bounties that haven't been given out but their questions contain LOTS of AWESOME and GREAT answers. Have this ever happened and if so, how will this be dealt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, users forget to give out their bounties. Is it done maliciously? I doubt it. There *are* some protective systems in place for this:

An *accepted* answer posted after the bounty started is automatically awarded the bounty.

Answers posted after the bounty with more than 2 upvotes (the highest scored such post, tiebreaker to the oldest post) is automatically awarded *half* the bounty.

For more information, see the help page for bounties: https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Answer (score 6):

As Bradley said, the system will split / award the bounty in this event, if the question gets any answers that the community thinks are valuable.

However, you can't really 'cheat' here, keep in mind the rep is *gone* forever once you start the bounty. Not awarding it would be a very odd pattern of abuse, I'd be more inclined to ascribe that to forgetfulness, and that's why we have the automatic awarding in place.

And, well, if you *don't* get the answer you needed after placing it, nothing should force you to award it, which is why it's left up to the system itself.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get good answers, you have to put effort into the question. Edit the question to provide status and progress updates. Document your own continued efforts to answer the question. This will naturally bump the question and get more people interested in it.

However, if after doing this, you feel a particular question still isn't getting enough attention, adding a bounty may help.